# Audio recording in Android, how to customize the recording experience?

Tags: android, file-io, audio-recording

I am recording Audio using,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

atartActivityForResult(intent, 1); // intent and requestCode 1
```

In the 
     protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

```
    if (requestCode == 1) {
   ...
              // lets get the uri
            Uri audioUri = data.getData();
```

'''

So, I have a audio pointed by audioUri.

1. How can I save a file from this Uri?
   Please also tell the format of audio.
2. Is it possible to change the look and feel of the GUI of the audio interface ..., i mean the interface that we see at the time of recording..

thanks